# How to increase the timeout in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using `waitFor()`. The code as below:

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return this.evaluate(someFunction, 'variable 1','variable 2','variable 3') === 'yes';
    });
}, function then() {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Am getting this as console output

```
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
```

How can I increase the timeout?

EDIT: I have changed the code to

```
 casper.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            return this.evaluate(someFunction, 'variable 1','variable 2','variable 3') === 'yes';
        });
    }, function then() {
        console.log('Done');
    },10000);
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
CasperError: Invalid timeout function, exiting.
    C:/filename:1720 in _check
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As said [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor),

The signature is

```
waitFor(Function testFx[, Function then, Function onTimeout, Number timeout])
```

So, there is an additionnal argument to specify the timeout.

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    //...
    });
}, function then() {
     //...
}, function timeout() { 
//...
}, TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
```

Comment: You can also set an option to increase the timeout. This will be the default for all timed functions. See the following link: [link](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#timeout)

Comment: Please see Edit. I have updated the code but am getting the error as shown in the edit

Comment: yes, in fact the third argument is onTimeout callback. Timeout value is the fourth.

Answer (score 58):

Use that to increase the timeout of every wait() functions : `casper.options.waitTimeout = 20000;`  (20sec)

Comment: this value will be used for the command of 
waitFor() and also wait() all in commons @Fanch ?

Comment: @gumuruh : yes ;) http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waittimeout `Default wait timeout, for wait* family functions.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase timeout while leaving the default error message, pass `null` as the third argument and number of milliseconds to wait as the fourth argument:

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return this.evaluate(someFunction, 'variable 1','variable 2','variable 3') === 'yes';
    });
}, function then() {
    console.log('Done');
}, null, 10000);
```